# How to forward cookies between client and server using NextJS server actions

Tags: next.js

I'm currently experimenting with NextJS 14 to understand how it could improve our user experience for clients. We currently have a very large SPA which is slow to load and most of which is not used by a client on a regular visit. I'm working on how or if performance on the client side can be improved using tools like SSR, dynamic rendering etc.

Our existing authentication flow is fairly standard. Authentication data is sent to the server (via. POST JSON) from the SPA on the client and exchanged for Cookies related to their session. At a very high level, it looks something like this:

[image: Existing authentication flow]

Our API is far too large to rewrite and so we're looking at using NextJS as a middle layer between the client and the API. Something like this:

[image: New flow]

We're trying to understand how, using server actions, we can forward cookies between the client and server via NextJS. For example, we currently have something like this as a custom layer over fetch for POST requests:

```
function post<T>(path: string, body: object, _headers?: Record<string, string>) {
    return fetch(requestUrl(path), {
        method: 'POST',
        credentials: 'include',
        headers: { ..._headers, 'Content-Type': 'application/json' },
        body: JSON.stringify(body)
    }).then(handleResponse<T>);
}
```

How can we proxy cookies from the server, to the client (and vice-versa) from the fetch request in our server action?

Answer (score 0):

In the end I went with this:

```
import setCookieParser from 'set-cookie-parser';
import { cookies } from 'next/headers';

export const proxyServerCookies = async (cookieNames: string[], response: Response) => {
    if (response.headers.has('set-cookie')) {
        const cookieString = response.headers.get('set-cookie')!;
        const cookieObject = setCookieParser.parse(setCookieParser.splitCookiesString(cookieString), {
            map: true,
        });

        cookieNames.forEach((cookieName) => {
            if (cookieObject[cookieName]) {
                const cookie = cookieObject[cookieName];

                console.debug(`[API Request] Proxying cookie ${cookieName} to client.`);

                cookies().set(cookieName, cookie.value, {
                    path: cookie.path,
                    domain: cookie.domain,
                    maxAge: cookie.maxAge,
                    sameSite: (cookie.sameSite as 'lax' | 'strict' | 'none' | boolean | undefined),
                    expires: cookie.expires,
                    secure: cookie.secure,
                    httpOnly: cookie.httpOnly,
                });
            }
        });
    }

    return response;
}
```

Usage is like:

```
function post<T>(path: string, body: object, _headers?: Record<string, string>, proxyCookies: boolean = false) {
    console.debug(`[API Request] POST ${path}`);

    return fetch(requestUrl(path), {
            method: 'POST',
            credentials: 'include',
            headers: { ..._headers, 'Content-Type': 'application/json' },
            body: JSON.stringify(body)
        })
        .then(proxyServerCookies(['COOKIE_NAME'], response))
        .then(handleResponse<T>);
}
```